# UIBarButtonItem added to storyboard does not appear at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

When I try to add a UIBarButtonItem to my UIViewController, nothing shows up at run time.

What I did:

1. I started off with a brand new single view project.
2. I dragged a UIBarButtonItem into the view controller.
3. I can now see and customize the item in the storyboard, but when I run it, there is no toolbar.

Note: the Bar Button Item appears as a direct child of View Controller.

How can I get the UIToolbar to appear?

Comment: just embed your view controller to a navigation controller in the storyboard

Answer (score 5):

Adding toolbar items as direct children of the UIViewController corresponds to the [toolbarItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW51) property of a view controller. The documentation states:

> If this view controller is embedded **inside a navigation controller**
>   interface, and the navigation controller **displays a toolbar**, this
>   property identifies the items to display in that toolbar.

So, you must do the following:

1. Embed the UIViewController in a UINavigationController (e.g. select the UIViewController in the storyboard, choose Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller).
2. Select the UINavigationController and check the box that says **Shows Toolbar** (this is the similar to calling `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO` in the view did load method).

Optionally, if you want to restore the behavior where the navigation bar wasn't visible, then uncheck the **Shows Navigation Bar** property.

An alternative approach is to not use the toolbarItems property, and instead add your own toolbar and maintain it yourself (e.g. add an IBOutlet and interact with it that way).